# How to use devise with multiple Engines without conflicts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Our app is structured as one core application that contains all of the models with many engines that power distinct sites.

gemfile:

```
gem 'rails', '4.1.1'
gem 'leadsengine', path: "engines/leadsengine"
gem 'profilesengine', path: "engines/profilesengine"
gem 'sourmilkengine', path: "engines/sourmilkengine"
gem 'reports', path: 'engines/reports'
```

Until recently, only one of these engines used Devise (leadsengine). We then added sourmilkengine and found that when a user attempts to log into /leadsengine, devise redirects them to /sourmilkengine. Reversing the order of the engines in the gem switches the redirect to whichever engine running Devise appears last.

routes.rb (leadsengine)

```
Leadsengine::Engine.routes.draw do

  devise_for :user, {
    class_name: 'User',
    module: :devise
  }
```

routes.rb (sourmilkengine)

```
Sourmilkengine::Engine.routes.draw do

  devise_for :user, {
    class_name: 'User',
    module: :devise
  }
```

I noted this rejected pull request https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/issues/2827 and wondered if a better solution has been found?